# How to close file handle after Application.run in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a kind of complex scenario

The Access-Application we are developing calls a VBA Function in another Access-Application which then triggers an Install Routine by calling the "calling" Access-Application.
Both Applications are either accda (for Access-AddIn) or compiled accde files.

Admin.accda -> PlugIn.accda (InstallPlugIn) -> Admin.accda (RegisterPlugIn)

The corresponding line in Admin.accda looks like:

```
Application.Run("\\Path\To\PlugIn\PlugIn.InstallPlugin", "Parameters")
```

Everything works as expected except for one thing. Access keeps the file handle on the PlugIn.accda open until I close the Admin.accda.

When I debug my Code I can see that after calling Application.Run() in Admin.accda the VBA-Code of PlugIn.accda gets loaded into Admin.accda and a Lockfile for PlugIn.accda (PlugIn.laccda) gets created. When my code finishes the Lockfile has 0 Bytes but still exists.

By using the ProcessExplorer from Sysinternals I can see that the Process in which the Admin.accda is running still has a Filehandle open to the PlugIn.accda.

I want to close that file handle because there is nothing more to do with the PlugIn.accda and the open Filehandle could interfere with Process in the Clients Client/Server deployment like copying the PlugIn to the Client Computer.

Until now I have tried two different approaches but without success:

First:
I tried to call the Run on Access-Application-Object and close that Object afterwards

```
  Dim oApplication As Object
  Set oApplication = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  oApplication.OpenCurrentDatabase Me.txtPathPlugIn
  If oApplication.Run("\\Path\To\PlugIn\PlugIn.InstallPlugin", "Params") Then
     'Do something
  End If
  oApplication.CloseCurrentDatabase
  Set oApplicaton = Nothing
```

With that approach the PlugIn was unable to call the RegisterPlugIn Function in the Admin.accda because it was exclusivly opened in another Process.

Second:
I tried to close the PlugIn Database after the call to RegisterPlugIn in the Admin.accda by using:

```
CodeProject.CloseCurrentDatabase
```

But that had no effect what so ever :-(

Is there a way to close File handles by using some Windows-API functions? Or does anyone has an better approach to dynamically register additional Access files?

Comment: Try calling 'oApplication.Quit' before you set 'oApplication' to nothing.  See if that releases the handle for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a dumb solution but just throwing it out there, you could use the taskkill command ? 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: +1 for "throwing it out there". I had to do something similar to kill "zombie" MSACCESS processes once, except that I used `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById().Kill` in a .NET app.